# Why is /etc/mtab a relative symlink

Tags: linux, nfs, mount, proxmox, zfsonlinux

I've just spent a few hours trying to figure out why NFS exports were not working on a Proxmox (based on Debian) server. "Not working" in this case means that the mount command times out on the client. After some digging (`dmesg`) I found that `rpc.mountd` on the server segfaulted right after it started. Some searching around then directed me to `/etc/mtab` and this is where my confusion really started:

```
$ ls -l /etc/mtab 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Jan 30 15:08 /etc/mtab -> ../proc/self/mounts
$ cat /etc/mtab 
cat: /etc/mtab: No such file or directory
```

For whatever reason, `/etc/mtab` is a *relative* link to `../proc/self/mounts`. If I make this an absolute link with

```
$ sudo ln -sfn /proc/self/mounts /etc/mtab

$ ls -l /etc/mtab 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Jan 30 15:10 /etc/mtab -> /proc/self/mounts
$ cat /etc/mtab 
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
...
```

then NFS exports just start to function as expected.

When checking other Debian-based machines (also other ones running Proxmox) I see that these also have `/etc/mtab` as a relative symlink and that it works. "Special" on this machine is that it uses **ZFS**, also for the root file system. So I can only assume that it is this that breaks the link.

So far it did not seem to hurt to make this link absolute, but I'd rather understand the reasoning behind. So here are the actual questions:

- Why is `/etc/mtab` a *relative* link? Is this to simplify chroot or something?
- Is there anything wrong with making it absolute?
- How can ZFS (assuming that this is really the root cause) break this link?

Comment: Could you please tell us how you have done that NFS export?

Comment: I've used both the normal /etc/exports and ZFS' `sharenfs` option, with the same result. The share is in use now so that I can't test on the actual system, but it might be that rpc.mountd even crashed without an export being enabled. I'll see if I can test it in a VM.

Comment: I can't imagine that ZFS is buggy, as it's often used for such use cases. I'm not so familiar with ZFS, but according to this tutoral https://blog.programster.org/sharing-zfs-datasets-via-nfs there are at least 2 ways to share a ZFS over NFS but you should never use both ways at the same time (maybe that would cause a segfault).

Comment: I've used both ways, but exclusively. They were not enabled at the same time. I'm trying if I can reproduce the issue in VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using absolute symlinks may be problematic, especially when mounting into non default locations.

```
opensuse:/mnt/etc # ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Jan 30 20:07 absolute_mtab -> /proc/self/mounts
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Jan 30 20:06 mtab -> ../proc/self/mounts
```

The absolute symlink may work, but it's pointing to the hosts own `/proc/` directory, which is clearly a big nono as it might cause big trouble when wrongly handled. On the other hand, the relative symlink doesn't work, as there is no `/mnt/proc` in this case, but that's not a problem, or at least, it should not be a problem.

The Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS) requires or demands that `/etc/` and `/proc/` must be located right on top of the `/` root-directory, if they are not on top, they are to be considered as non valid.

https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s07.html

Another important statement of the FHS is:

> The following files, or symbolic links to files, must be in /etc if
> the corresponding subsystem is installed:

This means, `/etc/mtab` must exist if the subsystem for dynamic mounting of filesystems is installed, which is the case for most of all modern Linux operating systems.

But a `/etc` directory, remounted to a `/mnt/etc` is not a valid `/etc` directory, in terms of FHS, so it would make sense to use only relative symlinks to make sure that nobody is using or changing files in an accident.

.

I'm not sure why you have encoutered a segfault here, but I would guess it's either a bug or you have a problem with your general configuration. I tend to think it's more like a software bug. You might try to update your software or report this bug to its creator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've accepted it, since it answers at least the first two of the questions. I'll add another answer for the third question about ZFS, since it appears that I've found out what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was just me (once again :S). I've installed Proxmox in a VM also with the root filesystem on ZFS to figure out what's going on. At first, everything was ok, `/etc/mtab` pointed to the relative location `../proc/self/mounts` and worked. Checking back on the faulty system, I found that I wasn't careful some time ago, when I took a snapshot of the root filesystem (/) dataset and sent it to a secondary pool for backup purposes. I've missed to disable the `canmount` property on the received dataset. This was no problem at first, but after some later reboot, ZFS mounted the original root dataset **and the backup dataset** to /. Interestingly the system mostly worked normally. But one consequence apparently is that the `/etc/mtab` relative link no longer works, causing the NFS server to segfault.

On the VM, I was able to reproduce this behavior by adding a second harddisk, creating a pool on it, sending and receiving a snapshot of rpool/ROOT/pve-1 to it and rebooting:

[image]

Reboot to break it...

[image]

Apply the fix, i.e., disable automatic mounting of the backup dataset:

[image]

Reboot to fix things...

[image]

All good again.